# Dash layout not shows

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm trying to create a dash in my company internal network (Because of security issues, we cannot connect to Internet). Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'BAS_DT': ['20210104','20210105','20210106','20210107','20210108'],
    'LIM': [22071,20775,20841,21891,22395],
    'APPR_LIM':[22000,22000,22000,22000,22000]})

df1.head()

#df1:
    BAS_DT  LIM APPR_LIM
0   20210104    22071   22000
1   20210105    20775   22000
2   20210106    20841   22000
3   20210107    21891   22000
4   20210108    22395   22000

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=frame_pivot['BAS_DT'],
        y=frame_pivot['CLOC_CUR_XC_BL'],
        name = "Credit Amount of Woori Bank Vietnam",
        mode='lines+markers+text',
        text = frame_pivot['CLOC_CUR_XC_BL'],
        textposition='top center',
        line_shape='spline'))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=frame_pivot['BAS_DT'],
        y=frame_pivot['Limit'],
        name = "SBV Approved Limit",
        mode='lines',
        line_shape='spline',
        line=dict(dash='dash')))

fig.update_traces(texttemplate='%{text:,}')
fig.update_layout(title={'text':"Credit Growth",'x':0.5,'xanchor':'center'},plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)')
fig.update_xaxes(showline=False,showgrid=False,tickangle=90)
fig.update_yaxes(showline=False,showgrid=False)

fig_2 = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(
    columnwidth=[15,15,15],
    header=dict(values=list(frame_pivot.columns),
                fill_color='paleturquoise',
                align='center'),
    cells=dict(values=[frame_pivot['BAS_DT'],frame_pivot['CLOC_CUR_XC_BL'],frame_pivot['Limit']],
               fill_color='lavender',
               align='center',
               format=[None,",.2f",",.2f"]))
])

import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_table
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash

app = dash.Dash(__name__,external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.DARKLY])

app.layout = dbc.Container([html.H1("Credit Growth",className="bg-primary text-white text-center"),
                           dbc.Row(
                               [
                                   dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(figure=fig),lg=8),
                                   dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(figure=fig_2),lg=4)
                               
                           ]),],fluid=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=False, port=8050)
```

It's worked on my laptop with Internet connection, but in my company's PC dash shows without layout:

## Laptop

[image]

## PC

[image]

I would like to ask is there anyway to fix it. Thanks and best regards.

Comment: Isn't it because the resolution (width) of PC and Laptop are different?

Comment: @r-beginners I'm not sure :(

Comment: Is it loading the style sheet correctly? Even the credit growth header doesn't appear to have the right styles.

Comment: @coralvanda I don't think it's loading correctly. I used same code on 2 different PC and it just run correctly on one of them.

Comment: Would you share your project structure?

Comment: @coralvanda: I downloaded css and added to assets folder and it worked.